# HTML textarea newline character

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline

I have a text area in `HTML` where the user can enter text, but when the form is submitted, and its passed to a `php` script which `echo`'s it, there aren't any newlines. Knowing that `HTML` does that, I tried doing a `preg_replace()` before echoing it...

```
    echo preg_replace("/\n/", "<br />", $_GET["text"]);
```

but still everything is on one line.

So my best guess is that `HTML` textareas use a different newline character... can anybody shed some light on the subject?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I've figured out the problem: The Javascript is stripping the newlines. [view code here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=w79aMvSv)

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so thanks to Jason for solving this problem. I needed to do:

```
    escape(document.getElementById('text'));
```

Instead of just:

```
    document.getElementById('text');
```

and the newlines are preserved, problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo nl2br($_GET['text'])
```

Though, your `preg_replace` worked for me!

Comment: When you view-source, are you printing a new line? As in, after you submit the form, `echo $_GET['text']` what do you see in the actual, unformatted HTML?

Comment: If I just directly `echo $_GET['text']`, I get everything all on one line... strange...

Comment: What are you getting in your query string? I get `%0D%0A` in place of `\n` in my QS (`+` in place of a space).

Comment: My query string just comes across as `asdfasdf`, when I put a newline between the asdfs in the form... Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=w79aMvSv

Comment: I'm using Javascript to load the page in with the get parameter set to the contents of the input textarea, so that way I enter new text and watch it update instantly.

Comment: So i think the Javascript is scraping the newlines out

Comment: try : `escape(document.getElementById('text').value)` That should work.

Comment: Uh oh, that's bad. You should be using `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_GET['text']))`

Comment: actually `nl2br(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['text'])))`.

Answer (score 0):

usually when testing for newlines in any string, I use `/[\n\r]/`, just to cover my bases. My guess is that this would match the new lines.

Comment: you might have some odd encoding, or possibly the breaks are being stripped out before you get the GET data? That regex will match any line break, I use it for a webapp right now (well, actually I use `'/([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]/'`, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are getting your breaks, stripped out also.

Comment: That appears to be what's happening... I'm primarily calling the page via Javascript... I'll pastebin the code

Comment: Good point, @Jesse, on including both CR and LF, but if you include them in the brackets (OR), you'll end up with duplicate `<br/>`. This is due to the HTML specification for browsers to submit both CR and LF on a form. You'd want something like `$newItem['about'] = preg_replace('/\r\n/', '<br/>', $newItem['about']);`